# Advantages of moving message parsing logic from spark to kafka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Currently, I am working on a use-case which requires reading JSON messages from Kafka and process them in Spark via Spark Streaming. We are expecting around 35 Million records per day. With this kind of a load, is it preferred to move the parsing logic (and some filtering logic based on JValue) to Kafka using Custom Kafka Deserializer (extending org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer class). Will this have any performance overhead?
Thank you.

Comment: You should look at Kafka's Streams API and KSQL too. Both give you high-performance, distributed, flexible stream processing capabilities against data in Kafka.

Comment: Thanks Robin for the quick reply. However, due to our complex processing logic we thought of going ahead with Spark Streaming instead of KStreams API.

Comment: Out of interest, what is it you can't do with KStreams that you will do with Spark Streaming?

Comment: Also out of interest, why not Avro? You could be saving so much network bandwidth with binary compression

Comment: our use case is about handling multiple stream of events happening at a random pace. And we need to have a join across these random streams which are not time bound. For example, a stream might come after 3 or 4 days and we need to join these two streams to arrive at some meaningful conclusion. Also, we have data in Hive which needs to be considered when joining these streams. Hence, planning for Spark.